# Meaning of Open parentheses surrounding a variable name during declaration?

Tags: kotlin, syntax

I've encountered strange syntax that I've never seen before in a Kotlin program. A variable is declared and instantiated with open parentheses surrounding it like this.

`val (filesystem) = ...`

What exactly does this do to the variable? It's still being passed around in the same way that I would expect a regular variable to behave.

Comment: The first thing that springs to mind is destructuring declarations, though that is usually with more than one variable. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html

Comment: Yes, this is destructuring of only the first item.