# name of variable with braces - what is it in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have such code:

```
val (valName) = list[fileAndMediaHolder.adapterPosition] as FileAndMediaItem
```

() - what is it in Kotlin?

Comment: It's in the basic documentation. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html

Comment: It's also been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68867893/3001761. Please do basic research before posting questions.

Comment: And just to correct the terminology: `(` `)` are brackets (or round brackets, parentheses, or parens); `{` `}` are braces (or curly brackets); `[` `]` are square brackets (or just brackets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it is convenient to destructure an object into a number of variables, for example:

```
val (name, age) = person
```